# Google showing "This site might be hacked" under search results

Tags: wordpress, spam

I have newly installed WordPress copy on my live server but on google search it show

```
"this site might be hacked "
```

message under my site link. i have applied the search console verification method of uploading html file into root folder but this error is not gone. checked into Security options tab it shows "content injection" spam issue with my site but i have not found any accurate method to solve that issue .

Comment: Search your server for viruses/malware. Check and see if your IP is on any blacklists. Depending on who you're hosting with, it may be best to clean your site and move to a different server. Good luck!

Comment: can you tell me how do i look for viruses and how to cleanup my site?

Comment: Personally, I use Linux Malware Detect (LMD) with ClamAV as the Antivirus Engine. A lot depends on your server.

Answer (score 0):

Carefully follow [FAQ - My Site Was Hacked - WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked).

Then take a look at the recommended security measures in [Hardening WordPress - WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress) and [Brute Force Attacks - WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Brute_Force_Attacks)

Change all passwords. Scan your own PC. Tell your web host you got hacked; and consider changing to a more secure host: [Recommended WordPress Web Hosting](http://wordpress.org/hosting/)

Answer (score 0):

You might find this page valuable, it seems to be talk specifically to the problem you are referring to with the warning: [How to Remove Google Blacklist Warnings](https://sucuri.net/guides/how-to-remove-google-blacklist-warning)

This warning seems to be specific to SEO spam. From what I understand there are many different things that might be contributing to this. I think if you do a Fetch as Google via the console you should see exactly what Google is seeing. These Sercuri folks seem to have another guide that might help you too: [How to Clean a WordPress Hack](https://sucuri.net/guides/how-to-clean-hacked-wordpress)

Good luck, keep us posted